# Why does ORDER by itself change the results in an Analytic function?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, analytic-functions

In the following query:

```
with SalesX as (
    select 'Office Supplies' Category , 2014 Year,22593.42 Profit UNION all
    select 'Technology', 2014, 21492.83 UNION all
    select 'Furniture', 2014,   5457.73 UNION all
    select 'Office Supplies',   2015,   25099.53  UNION all
    select 'Technology',    2015,   33503.87  UNION all
    select 'Furniture', 2015,   50000.00  UNION all
    select 'Office Supplies',   2016,   35061.23  UNION all
    select 'Technology',    2016,   39773.99  UNION all
    select 'Furniture', 2016,   6959.95
) select Category, Year, Profit,
    SUM(Profit) OVER (),
    SUM(Profit) OVER (ORDER BY Category, Year)
 from SalesX order by category, year
```

We see that using only an `ORDER BY <field>` in the query changes the results drastically (from a constant grand total to a running total):

[image]

My question is what is the reasoning behind the `ORDER` changing how the analytic function works. I know it *does*, but I'm more interested in why or how it does that (for example, a normal `ORDER BY` doesn't change the results, only if something like a limit is applied after it). Note the backend here is BigQuery for the tests but I think this question should apply to any DB that supports these functions.

Comment: Without an order by, it's across the entire window. With order by, it's from the first row of the window to the current row. (SQL Server example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#order-by)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The field in ORDER BY affects the result of window functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57243391/the-field-in-order-by-affects-the-result-of-window-functions)

Comment: @GSerg oh it seems to implicitly add the `ROWS BETWEEN PRECENDING AND UNBOUNDED` .

Comment: Hello @David542, Indeed, if you check the [official bigquery documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/analytic-function-concepts#def_over_clause) if we just use over a set of default parameters will run alongside it.

Comment: It's that enough to solve your question? or you are looking for something additional on it?